# Implementing Select2 plugin into Wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, customization, html, select

I am currently trying to implement the Select2 plugin in my Wordpress site to get the beautiful dropdown select boxes that allow users to select multiple items.

I have pasted the following code into the  of my HTML as per instructions on the plugin site:

```
<link href="path/to/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <script src="path/to/select2.min.js"></script>`
Then, it says to use this code: 

    <script type="text/javascript"> $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2(); </script> <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"> <option value="AL">Alabama</option> ... <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> </select>
```

Can anyone explain the steps to a noob?
It would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Share some code with us.

Comment: Sorry, I have pasted the following code into the <head> of my HTML as per instructions on the plugin site: 
<link href="path/to/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="path/to/select2.min.js"></script>

Then, it says to use this code:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
I just don't know how to use it in my own site.

Comment: Rather than pasting code into a comment (which is hard to read), please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/254518/edit) to add in the relevant code and any other details.

Comment: Just reformatted it, sorry its a horizontal view I didn't know how to make it into a normal block of code.